# MVC3 Dropdown selection based on other Drop down value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, selection

Hi there im working on MVC3 and have problem with dropdown selection:
I have a table call CSystem and it hold value System1 and System2
another table call SystemModule hold System1Module and System2Module

But at dropdown selection at job view when System1 is selected the SystemModule still appear all value. Please help.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create() 
{ 
   ViewBag.CSystemID = new SelectList(db.CSystems, "CSystemID", "SystemName");
   ViewBag.SystemModuleID = new SelectList(db.SystemModules.Where(x => x.CSystemID == CSystems.CSystemID), "SystemModuleID", "ModuleName"); 

   return View(); 
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="editor-label"> 
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SystemModuleID, "SystemModule") 
</div> 
<div class="editor-field"> 
   @Html.DropDownList("SystemModuleID", String.Empty) 
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SystemModuleID) 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you aren't passing in a model? I don't understand exactly what you are asking, but that is one glaring thing I can see in your code... hope this helps :\

Comment: um.. at my view Page I have 2 dropdown box for input and those data are based on diffrence databases.

both tables are showed in my view but the problem is i only wan it to show the data which is selected

such when System dropdown selected as System1, then then SystemModule dropdown will only appear the data belong to System 1.

But at the moment don;t matter what system i selected the modules still show all System modules.

Sorry about my english.

Comment: Oh I get what you are saying... You need to add in some javascript to adjust the selected index. The drop down is being populated fine, but it has no way of knowing when the other drop down is being changed.